# How to get a "Camera removed" event in MFCaptureEngine

Tags: c++, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

Is there any possibility to get an information that a camera was removed during preview in IMFCaptureEngine?

I am using a code from this sample [CaptureEngine video capture sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Media-Foundation-Capture-78504c83). There is an EventCallback connected to the MFCaptureEngine instance:

```
    hr = m_pEngine->Initialize(m_pCallback, pAttributes, NULL, pUnk);
```

But no event is received in the callback function after the webcam is removed.

I tried to add an extra callback function for engine's IMFMediaSource, which should, as I was expecting, generate MEVideoCaptureDeviceRemoved event. Look at the code called after MFCaptureEngine instance is initialized:

```
    m_pEngine->GetSource(&pCapSource);
    pCapSource->GetCaptureDeviceSource(MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_DEVICE_TYPE_VIDEO, &pMediaSource);
    pMediaSource.QueryInterface(&m_pSourceEventGenerator);
    hr = m_pSourceEventGenerator->BeginGetEvent(OnSourceCB, NULL);
```

The hr value is MF_E_MULTIPLE_SUBSCRIBERS, which gives me a sence, because there are mixed two callbacks objects (first for the MFCaptureEngine as a whole, second for IMediaSource only).

Why I don't get any information about the device was removed? How can I get this information?

PS. I know the WM_DEVICECHANGE message, but I would like to avoid this if possible to get an event from media foundation.

Answer (score 1):

You expectedly hit `MF_E_MULTIPLE_SUBSCRIBERS` because it's capture engine who is the subscriber here. The engine is supposed to handle the event internally and forward it to the owner in the form of `IMFMediaEvent` of extended type `MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_ERROR`, with `HRESULT` code indicated by `IMFMediaEvent::GetStatus` call of `MF_E_VIDEO_RECORDING_DEVICE_INVALIDATED` (0xC00D3EA2): "The video recording device is no longer present.".

You receive the event in your `IMFCaptureEngineOnEventCallback` implementation supplied to capture engine on initialization step.

Comment: This is exactly what, I expect, should be done. But it doesn't. I am wondering if there is any attribute which should be set to force the Capture Engine to dispatch the event.

Comment: Before posting I checked my Logitech C930e camera and it showed the described behavior a few times in a row, except just one time when the notification did not arrive on time and was triggered later when I stopped the capture session. I assume there might be related issues with unplugging, such as - I am guessing - third party software interfering with the intended behavior.

Comment: If you feel like going deeper in troubleshooting this behavior, perhaps you would want to instantiate and start the media source directly and check if you see that internal `MEVideoCaptureDeviceRemoved` event (or maybe you can see it with the help of mftrace). I would expect Capture Engine to work well and if something is broken it's higher on the way and you would not see `MEVideoCaptureDeviceRemoved` either.